# How to let crawlers have to run javascript in pages?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

I want to implement some anti-crawler mechanism to protect data in my site. After reading many related topics in SO, I am going to focus on "enforce running javascript".

My plan is:

1. Implement a special function F (eg. MD5SUM) in javascript file C

   Input: cookie string of current user (the cookie changes in each response)

   Output: a verification string V
2. Send V along with other parameters to sensitive backend interface to request valuable data
3. Backend server has validation function T to check whether V is correct

The difficult part is how to obfuscate F. If crawlers can easily understand F, they will get V without C and bypass javascript.

Indeed, there are many js obfuscators, but I am going achieve the goal by implement a generator function G which is not appear in C.

G(K) generates F, where K is a large integer. F should be complicate enough, so that crawler writers have to take many hours to understand F. Given another K', 
G(K') = F', F' should look like a new function in some extent, and again, crawler writers have to take hours to crack.

A possible implementation of G might be a mapping from integer to a digital circuit of many connected logic gates (like a maze). Using javascript grammar to represent it as F. Since F must be run in javascript, crawlers have to run PhantomJS. Furthermore, I can insert sleeps in F to slow down crawlers while normal users hardly aware 50-100ms delay.

I know there is a group of methods to detect crawlers. They will be applied. Let's only discuss "enforce running javascript" topic.
Could you give me some advice? Is there any better solution?

Comment: A good crawler will get through it all... Protect your data through a login mechanism

Comment: @Salketer Do you mean captcha (or login with captcha)? Login can resolved, it's only an http request.

Comment: @Salketer Yes. All requests in my post are in login state. There is no anonymous request because sensitive interfaces are only access-able by login users.

Answer (score 1):

Using login to prevent the whole world to see the data is one option.

If you do not want logged in users to fetch all the data you make available to them, you could then limit the number of requests per minute for the user, adding a delay to your page load if it has been reached. Since the user is logged, you could easily track the requests server-side even if they manage to change cookies/localStorage/IP/Browser and whatnot.

You can use images for some texts, that will force them to use some resource-heavy mechanics to translate to usable information.

You could add hidden texts, this would even prevent users' copy/paste (you use spans filled with 3-4 random letters on every 3-4 real letter and make them font-size 0). That way they aren't seen, but still copied, and most likely will be taken from crawler.

Refuse connection from known crawler HTTP header signatures, although any crawler could mock those. And greasemonkey or some scripting extension could even turn a regular browser into a crawler so this has very little incidence.

### Now, to force using javascript

The problem is that you cannot really force any javascript execution. What the javascript does is seen by everyone who has access to the page, so if it's some kind of MD5 hash you'd accomplish, this can be implemented in any language.

That's mainly unfeasible because the crawler has access to exactly everything the client's javascript has access to.

Forcing to use a javascript enabled crawler can be circumvented, and even if not, with the computing power available to anyone nowaday, it is very easy to launch a phantomJS instance... And as I said above, anyone with slight javascript knownledge can simply automate clicks on your website using their browser, which will make everything undetectable.

### What should be done

The only bulletproof way to prevent crawlers to leech your data, and to prevent any automation is to ask something that only a human could do. Captcha comes to mind.

### Think about your real users

First thing you should keep in mind is that is your website starts to get annoying to use for normal users, they will not come back. Having to type a 8 character captcha on each page request just because there MIGHT be someone who wants to pump the data will become too tedious for anyone. Also, blocking unknown browser agents might prevent legit users from accessing your website because of X or Y reason they are using a weird browser.

The impact on your legit users, and the time you'd take working hard on fighting crawlers might be too high to just accept that some crawling will happen. So your best bet is to rewrite your TOS to explicitly forbid crawling of any sort, log every http access of every user, and take action when needed.

> Disclaimer:
>   I'm scrapping over a hundred websites monthly, following external
>   links to totalise about 3000 domains. At the time of posting, none of
>   them are resisting, while they employ one or more techniques of the
>   above. When a scrapping error is detected, it does not take long to
>   fix it...
>
> The only thing is to crawl respectfully, not over crawl or make too
>   many requests in a small time frame. Just doing that will circumvent
>   most popular anti crawlers.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I'll vote +1 for some insight, but the answer is off-topic. I want to build several firewalls to defend crawlers. The first one is "force crawlers to run PhantomJS". Indeed, they can simulate user behaviors, but they will pay much more than simple urlopen. If they cannot understand what my js does, they have to run it from time to time.  Other protections, such as backend counting/captcha, are additional firewalls behind this one.

Comment: What I was saying is that there is no need for phantomJS, they could simply take your firewall javascript and run it on their nodeJS crawler. There is absolutely no sure way to force phantomJS. There are just ways to make your maintenance/expenses higher. It all depends on why your data is so private.

Comment: And although it does not answer your question on the "How to" part, I'd like to think that it is still on topic as it greatly describes why you CANNOT do it.

Comment: Maybe I did not express it clearly. I want to "force crawlers to run my js program" in whatever a real browser or PhantomJS or node.js or any other js executor/simulator.

Comment: Maybe I did not express it clearly. If javascript can do it, ActionScript, C#, C++, C, Python, PHP, Go and all friends can do it too.

Comment: Yep, that's the core part! If javascript can do it, then other language can do it too. However, you have to understand what my js do, then you can rewrite it in other language. The problem is, if my js is hard to understand, the rewrite cost is inacceptable. Not to mention F may change. That's why generator G(K) is very important.